# Example of Spring Security JWT library for work with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I want to authenticate and authorization a REST Spring API with `Spring Security JWT` for work with `AngularJS App`. but I confused and I don't know what should I do? I need to simple example for authenticate AngularJS app with Spring Security JWT.

Answer (score 0):

I used Jhipster token based authentication with spring security, you can easily modify the code to use JWT instead.

> [link to Jhipster](https://jhipster.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you give an example?

Comment: The link contains instruction to generate sample project. You can generate token based authentication project(example) if you follow the instruction on command line while generating the project. It is pretty simple. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Welcome to the JHipster Generator

? (1/13) What is the base name of your application? stackoverflowQuestion
? (2/13) What is your default Java package name? com.mycompany.myapp
? (3/13) Do you want to use Java 8? Yes (use Java 8)
? (4/13) Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? (Use arrow keys)
❯ HTTP Session Authentication (stateful, default Spring Security mechanism) 
  OAuth2 Authentication (stateless, with an OAuth2 server implementation) 
  Token-based authentication (stateless, with a token)